# How to upload file in variable via POST, Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have the form:

```
<form method='post'><textarea name='xml' cols=70 rows=20></textarea><input type='submit'></form>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="input" accept="xml" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

How I can upload file in `xml` variable via `POST`? Use `Retrofit 2`.

Comment: You should send  that from body of your request not header.

Comment: I have the textarea which I need send xml query and press button submit, then I will get an answer. How I can it in retrofit? How do I specify that the data should be sent in `<textarea name='xml'>`?

Comment: Retrofit does not inject data into HTML forms. It sends data to that URL as a POST request.

Comment: no, I need just insert query in xml variable. how do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking here, but as per the title, in order to upload a file from Retrofit 2 in Android, you can use `@Multipart` attribute. For example;

```
@Multipart
@POST("/task/attachments")
Call<JsonElement> postAttachment(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> files);
```

Then call the `postAttachment()` method by constructing `Map<String, RequestBody>` as per the following example:

```
final File file = getXmlFile();
final Map<String, RequestBody> body = new HashMap<>();

body.put("file\"; filename=\"" + "input" + "\"",
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/xml"), file));
Call<JsonElement> attachmentCall = mProvider.postAttachment(body);
```

Comment: I need just insert query in xml variable. how do it?